# Cannot create NFS on a tmpfs drive

Tags: mount, nfs, sles, tmpfs, ramdisk

OS: SLES 12.3

Running these commands:

```
mkdir /foo/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=100m tmpfs /foo/ramdisk
```

Creating a NFS on `/foo/ramdisk` produces this result when I run `showmount -e <IP>`:

> clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered

When I remove the NFS share then `showmount -e <IP>` works again:

> Export list for ...

---

**Another strange fact:**

When I create an NFS for `/foo` and I mount this NFS on another Linux/Windows PC then [on the PC where I mounted the NFS] there are **no** files visible in `/foo/ramdisk` and I am **not** allowed [yes, there are the correct permissions set] to write anything into the `/foo/ramdisk` directory.

---

I export the NFS with the SUSE tool *yast* and use these settings:

> crossmnt,rw,no_root_squash,async,no_subtree_check

---

**My question:**

Isn't it allowed to export a ramdisk as NFS or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the command(s) you run to export the NFS share from the ramdisk?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am doing it with the _yast_ tool. These are the options `crossmnt,rw,no_root_squash,async,no_subtree_check`

Comment: Yast is alien to me, but the RPC error sounds suspiciously like its telling you that the NFS server service is not running.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, Google finds only threads saying the same. But the service is running - I checked it. When I remove the share then it works again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I found the problem:** I had to add to the NFS options `fsid` so now the full list looks like this:

> fsid=1,crossmnt,rw,no_root_squash,async,no_subtree_check

The fact is *yast* doesn't warn here. I could fix the problem because I ran `exportfs` and then I got the error regarding the `fsid`.